# What is entryComponents in angular ngModule?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I am working on an `Ionic` app ( `2.0.0-rc0` ) which depends on `angular 2` . So the new introduction of `ngModules` is included. I am adding my `app.module.ts.` below.

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Users } from '../pages/users/users';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Users
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Users
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What does `entryComponents` do here? `Components` are already defined in `declarations` . So what's the need of repeating them ? What would happen if I dont include a component here?

Comment: Angular uses entryComponents to enable "tree shaking" i.e. only compiling the components that are actually used in the project instead of compiling all the components that are `declared` in `ngModule` but are never used. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#why-does-angular-need-_entrycomponents_-

Answer (score 188, accepted):

**Note: EntryComponent is Deprecated from Angular 9.0.0**
See the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#the-entrycomponents-array) form more details.

This is for dynamically added components that are added using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`. Adding them to `entryComponents` tells the offline template compiler to compile them and create factories for them.

The components registered in route configurations are added automatically to `entryComponents` as well because `router-outlet` also uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to add routed components to the DOM.

Offline template compiler (OTC) only builds components that are actually used. If components aren't used in templates directly the OTC can't know whether they need to be compiled. With entryComponents you can tell the OTC to also compile these components, so they are available at runtime.

[What is an entry component? (angular.io)](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-an-entry-component)

[NgModule docs (angular.io)](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#entryComponents)

> Defines the components that should be compiled as well when this component is defined. For each components listed here, Angular will create a ComponentFactory and store it in the ComponentFactoryResolver.

If you don't list a dynamically added component to `entryComponents` you'll get an error message a bout a missing factory because Angular won't have created one.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Comment: frankly speaking, I know its 100% correct answer but went bouncer for me, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Hard to tell what's unclear. Offline template compiler (OTC) only builds components that are actually used. If components aren't used in templates directly the OTC can't know whether they need to be compiled. With `entryComponents` you can tell the OTC to also compile this components so they are available at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Gunter .  Can you give me  a scenario in which not adding components in ``entryComponents`` would cause some issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 would be such an example

Comment: So in general, if component is listed in `declarations` it should also be listed in `entryComponents`, right?

Comment: only if a component is added dynamically with `createComponent` in your code or for example the router that also uses thod API to add components.

Comment: Do I need entryComponent if I always use JIT compiler?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do because it's also required in Plunker AFAIR. Should be pretty easy to find out I guess.

Comment: My list of such components in ionic2 app is quite big so I made a concat of entryComponents for declarations: ```let declarations = entryComponents.concat([
 additionalDeclarations, ...
]);```

Comment: `entryComponents` is deprecated from Angular version 9 see my answer further down for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946581/1494989

Comment: I end up at StackOverflow questions/answers like this when I'm trying to do something like in Angular 16 days run a sample that was written in Angular 9.  I needed to redo package.json to 16.0.0 entries instead of 9.0.0 to get rid of some errors.  Then I got "'entryComponents' does not exist in type 'NgModule'".  The offending line was in main.ts and simply eliminating the "entryComponents: [TheSpecificClassInTheDemoApp]," line resolved the error and the app ran.

Answer (score 64):

The other answers mention this but the basic summary is:

- It's needed when a Component is NOT used in the **html** , ex: `<my-component />`
- For example with Angular Material Dialogs you use them *indirectly*, they are created inside the **TS code** and not the html:

```
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyExampleDialog, { width: '250px'});
}
```

This requires you to register it as an entryComponent:

- `entryComponents: [MyExampleDialog]`

Otherwise you get a error:

- `ERROR Error: No component factory found for MyExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Comment: The best explanation over here.

Comment: Simple, thank you. XD

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer tends to be the best one.

Answer (score 34):

You won't get explanation better than Angular docs: [entry-components](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) and [ngmodule-faq](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

And below is the explanation from the angular docs.

> An entry component is any component that Angular loads imperatively by  type.
>
> A component loaded declaratively via its selector is not an entry component.
>
> Most application components are loaded declaratively. Angular uses the component's selector to locate the element in the template. It then creates the HTML representation of the component and inserts it into the DOM at the selected element. These aren't entry components.
>
> A few components are only loaded dynamically and are never referenced in a component template.
>
> The bootstrapped root `AppComponent` is an entry component. True, its selector matches an element tag in index.html. But `index.html` isn't a component template and the `AppComponent` selector doesn't match an element in any component template.
>
> Angular loads AppComponent dynamically because it's either listed by type in `@NgModule.bootstrap` or boostrapped imperatively with the module's ngDoBootstrap method.
>
> Components in route definitions are also entry components. A route definition refers to a component by its type. The router ignores a routed component's selector (if it even has one) and loads the component dynamically into a `RouterOutlet`.
>
> The compiler can't discover these entry components by looking for them in other component templates. You must tell it about them by adding them to the `entryComponents` list.
>
> Angular automatically adds the following types of components to the module's `entryComponents`:
>
> - The component in the `@NgModule.bootstrap` list.
> - Components referenced in router configuration.
>
> You don't have to mention these components explicitly, although doing so is harmless.

Comment: Right now the angular docs are not available, so thank SO for that!

Comment: This doesn't seem to mention that components in route configurations are automatically added to entryComponents (so you usually never need to define it).

Comment: If we create a component to be used as an `EntryComponent` should we remove the `selector` attribute? (since it won't be used)

Comment: Best answer for a newbie

Answer (score 12):

As of Angular **9** `entryComponents` is no longer required thanks to Ivy allowing this feature to be deprecated and so can be removed from module declarations.

[Deprecated APIs and features - `entryComponents` and `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` no longer required](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required)

> Previously, the `entryComponents` array in the `NgModule` definition was used to tell the compiler which components would be created and inserted dynamically. With Ivy, this isn't a requirement anymore and the `entryComponents` array can be removed from existing module declarations. The same applies to the `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` injection token.

[Angular Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

> Ivy is the code name for Angular's next-generation compilation and rendering pipeline. With the version 9 release of Angular, the new compiler and runtime instructions are used by default instead of the older compiler and runtime, known as View Engine.

Comment: Doesn't answers the question but it's still an informative answer. +1.

Answer (score 6):

The entryComponents array is used to define only components that are not found in html and created dynamically. Angular requires this hint to find entry component and compile them.

There are two main types of entry components:

- The bootstrapped root component.
- A component you specify in a route definition.

For more detailed information around entry components, please refer angular.io 
https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

Answer (score 5):

With Angular 13.1, EntryComponent is deprecated. Refs: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1310-2021-12-09

See also: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required

Answer (score 2):

### A Bit of Background about `entryComponent`

`entryComponent` is any component Angular loads imperatively. You can declare `entryComponent` by bootstrapping it in `NgModule` or in route definitions.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // bootstrapped entry component
})
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) says below

> To contrast the two types of components, there are components which
>   are included in the template, which are declarative. Additionally,
>   there are components which you load imperatively; that is, entry
>   components.

### Now to answer your specific question about `entryComponents`

There is `entryComponents` array in `@NgModule` file. You can use this to add `entryComponents` if component is bootstrapped using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`.

**That is you're creating components dynamically and not by bootstrapping or in template.**

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(myComp.component);
const viewContainerRef = this.compHost.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```