# angular 2 routing throwing error even I have entry in @NgModule of app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have implemented angular 2 routing but it's throwing error as

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for
>   AdminpanelComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Even though I have entry in app.module entryComponents still I am facing this errro. Details of code below.

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import { AdminpanelComponent } from './components/adminpanel/adminpanel.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

export const AppRoutes: any = [
    { path: '', component: 'LoginComponent'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminpanelComponent },
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const AppComponents: any = [
    LoginComponent,
    AdminpanelComponent
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthService} from './services/auth.service'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AdminpanelComponent } from './components/adminpanel/adminpanel.component';
import { BalldetailsComponent } from './components/balldetails/balldetails.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponents, AppRoutes } from "./app.routes";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppComponents,
    NavbarComponent,
    AdminpanelComponent,
    BalldetailsComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    AppComponents,
    NavbarComponent,
    AdminpanelComponent,
    BalldetailsComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...Thanks

Comment: I don't see it in your entryComponents

Comment: As per my understanding, we put entry in declaration which is entry point? Am I wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756192/what-is-entrycomponents-in-angular-ngmodule

Comment: You are declaring it two times: standalone and as an element of the AppComponents-array (btw you shouldn't name variables starting with uppercase). Also you are importing RouterModule two times. And you are missing CommonModule (which you need for *ngFor and other angular directives which you are probably using)

Comment: @JanS added entryComponents as per the link but still error is there? can u guide me what is wrong?